# Start a method when another finishes using multi-threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm looking for a way to start a method as soon as another has finished. So this is the idea:

1st `Parallel.Invoke` will start, as soon as for example `GetGroups()` is done I would like to start `InsertGroup()` and after that `Insert_EventGroups()`.

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => { GetGroup(); },
                () => { GetProfile(); });

Parallel.Invoke(() => { InsertGroup(); },
                () => { InsertProfile(); });

Parallel.Invoke(() => { Insert_EventGroups(); },
                () => { Insert_GroupProfiles(); });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just run a task that just calls each method in turn?

Comment: If you were using `Task` you could use the `.ContinueWith` API.

Comment: I agree with @Matthew Watson. Why do you even need threading here? If the methods are to be called one after another, just call them sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these methods are non-task returning then the correct approach is to simply put them in the order you'd like. By default, **C#** will execute sequentially so the order of the method calls are the order in which they are to execute.

```
private void PerformGroupUpdate()
{
    GetGroup();
    InsertGroup();
    Insert_EventGroups();
}

private void PerformProfileUpdate()
{
    GetProfile();
    InsertProfile();
    Insert_GroupProfiles();
}
```

If you were to use [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx) it would run these methods in parallel and not necessarily keep the order. So you could now call the two perform methods above to execute them as you see fit. Additionally, if you'd like them to run concurrently that could be achieved by using the `Parallel.Invoke` and passing in these two new methods.

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => PerformGroupUpdate(), () => PerformProfileUpdate());
```

If these methods were `async` methods, then you could use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private async Task PerformGroupUpdateAsync()
{
    await GetGroup();
    await InsertGroup();
    await Insert_EventGroups();
}

private async TaskPerformProfileUpdateAsync()
{
    await GetProfile();
    await InsertProfile();
    await Insert_GroupProfiles();
}

private async Task InvokeAllAsync() 
    => await Task.WhenAll(PerformGroupUpdateAsync(), TaskPerformProfileUpdateAsync());
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for the groups and profiles to be processes concurrently, even though the operations specific to each collection of operations needs to be sequential.

Answer (score 4):

Just call them sequentially, if you want multi threading for group and profile you can do something like the below (renaming the methods to something more appropriate):

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => { GroupStuff(); },
                () => { ProfileStuff(); });

void GroupStuff()
{
    GetGroup();
    InserGroup();
    Insert_EventGroups();
}

void ProfileStuff()
{
    GetProfile();
    InserProfile();
    Insert_GroupProfiles();
}
```